# PL/SQL read from Oracle Package defined cursor, return SYS_REFCURSOR, using cx_Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, cx-oracle

I need to use cx_Oracle to use a legacy Oracle database, and a Oracle cursor that is defined in an Oracle PACKAGE such as:

```
PACKAGE MY_PACKAGE AS
  cursor my_cur (
    p_1 number
  ) is
    select ... (long complex select):
```

I can define an Oracle FUNCTION to return data from my_cur as a SYS_REFCURSOR, but I first need to create a "temp" table to read the data from the cursor, and then return a SYS_REFCURSOR that runs select * from this temp table:

```
type temp_table is table of my_cur%rowtype;

FUNCTION my_func(p_1 in number) return SYS_REFCURSOR as
  i number := 1;
  my_table temp_table := new temp_table();
  p_result_cur SYS_REFCURSOR;
begin
  for r in my_cur(p_1)
  loop
    my_table.extend();
    my_table(i) := r;
    i := i + 1;
  end loop;

  open p_result_cur for
    select * from table(my_table);

  return p_result_cur;
 end;
```

This seems very inefficient. I think there must be a better way to do this? Can cx_Oracle fetch data more directly from the Oracle PACKAGE level my_cur?

Comment: cx_Oracle needs to call a PL/SQL function or a procedure by name.  Once you have a cursor in a state to return from a func or proc, then you can use cx_Oracle `callfunc()` or `callproc()`, see [RefCursor.py](https://github.com/oracle/python-cx_Oracle/blob/master/samples/RefCursor.py) for one example.  I'll leave the PL/SQL side of the question (about the most efficient way to get a returnable sys_refcursor from the package global) to a PL/SQL expert.

Comment: cx_Oracle documentation on working with REF CURSORS is [here](https://cx-oracle.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user_guide/bind.html#ref-cursor-bind-variables).

Comment: Thank you Christopher. Yes, I am using cx_Oracle callfunc() to call my_func. My question was more on the PL/SQL side, if I needed to first loop through my_cur, copy the results into a table, and then return another cursor that was a select from that table. It seems that there should be a way to use my_cur directly?

Comment: You might want to update the subject and question to attract PL/SQL experts to read this post.  Or ask on asktom.oracle.com.